# Debian ffmpeg сжирает ресурсы сервера. Можно ли ограничить ffmpeg 50% ресурсов?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ffmpeg, cpu

У меня VPS. Если одновременно вызвать обработку нескольких видео-файлов, то ffmpeg в итоге сжирает все ресурсы и скрипты (PHP, MySQL) очень медленно выполняются! Бывает и "превышен лимит ожидания" в какой-то момент.

Я прекрасно понимаю, что можно взять более мощный сервер и проблемы уйдут. Вопрос в другом, можно ли имея одно ядро на VPS ограничить потребление CPU от ffmpeg не выше 50%? Грубо говоря указать приложению (ffmpeg или другому) максимально допустимые лимиты?

Или если есть 2 ядра (2 core) VPS настроить так, чтобы работал ffmpeg только на одном ядре, а nginx+php-fpm+mysql на втором?

Уточню, я не против, чтобы видео обрабатывались в 2-3 раза дольше через ffmpeg, лишь бы сайт стабильно работал.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

можно использовать программу *nice*. вместо:

```
$ программа аргументы
```

запускайте:

```
$ nice программа аргументы
```

---

это повлияет на планировщик задач: процессы с более высоким значением «niceness» получат меньше тактов процессора, чем те, у которых «niceness» ниже. пользовательские процессы обычно получают «niceness», равную 0.

минимальное значение «niceness» — -20 (наивысший приоритет процесса), максимальное — 19 (наинизший приоритет).

с помощью опции `-n число` можно указать величину, которую следует добавить к текущему значению «niceness» (оно наследуется дочерними процессами от родительского). если не указывается, прибавляется 10.

увидеть «niceness» процессов можно, например, в выводе программы *top* (столбец *NI*), или в выводе программы *ps* примерно так:

```
$ ps -eo pid,user,args,nice --sort nice
```

---

а с помощью программы *renice* можно изменить «niceness» у уже запущенного процесса.

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ man nice
$ man renice
```